# How to Launch OpenNI for KINECT

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble launching OpenNI in ROS. Here is the code that is generated in the terminal. Please help!

```
...auto-starting new master

process[master]: started with pid [2865]

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to b94a6992-7a85-11e0-9542-d48564bff373

process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2878]

started core service [/rosout]

process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [2886]

process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [2890]

process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [2892]

process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [2893]

process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [2894]

[ INFO] [1304977559.799925062]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1

[ INFO] [1304977559.800176015]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:07 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00365709867102B'

[ INFO] [1304977559.802737337]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1

[ INFO] [1304977559.848618180]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:7 with serial number 'B00365709867102B'

[ INFO] [1304977559.863246868]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 

[ INFO] [1304977559.865246392]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9927/how-to-launch-openni-for-kinect/) by [eabryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/515/eabryan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-09

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eabryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/515/eabryan/) on 2011-05-09**:
Also, I can not post the output from rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points because when I enter that command, the terminal does not respond.

**Comment by [eabryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/515/eabryan/) on 2011-05-09**:
The problem is: The terminal stops after those two lines. Shouldn't I be able to enter additional commands? The terminal window behaves as if it's still working on some part of the program.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-09**:
What exactly is the problem you are having? That looks like normal startup for the openni_node. Can you post the output of 'rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points'? That will tell you if the driver is actually streaming data that you could then examine in rviz.

**Comment by [eabryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/515/eabryan/) on 2011-05-09**:
... the last two lines are: [ INFO] [1304977559.863246868]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1304977559.865246392]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is entirely normal behavior. After successfully launching, the terminal will not allow you enter additional commands, as the driver is still working - it is in fact in the actual data streaming loop.

In order to run additional commands (such as `rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points` or `rosrun rviz rviz`), you will have to open new terminal windows to enter them in.

If you are new to ROS, I suggest you go through the [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) to get a feel for how you normally start, interact with and write ROS nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4